# What is a "dip relay" and how does one use it to build a transmitter?

Tags: transmitter

Reading a [discussion on low parts count transmitters](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.radio.amateur.homebrew/P64BnNdc3dc), I came across this description, which lacked schematics and build instructions:

> Re: PROJECT 14: THE WORLD'S SMALLEST TRANSMITTER
>
> Are y'all forgetting the Fireball transmitter?
>   Battery, key, dip relay, xtal oscillator at 29.060, antenna.
>   I think this about as minimalist as anyone could go.
>
> Grover
>   WT6P

The part that is confusing me is the "dip relay" - a quick search suggests it may be shorthand for a DPDT (double pole, double throw) relay.  But in the RF world there's something called "dip tuning" so I'm confused as to whether the terminology is related.

How would one use the above components to make a CW transmitter?

Comment: Could be a tiny reed relay in a Dual-Inline-Package.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I think you should put that in your answer. That's my take on it also.

Comment: Doing a search on digikey.com yields [59 examples](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/relays/reed-relays/964?k=dip%20relay) of reed relays in DIP-compatible packages.  So, yup :-)

Comment: WT6B seems to have been re-assigned. And, the 1994 date on the original post pre-dates widespread internet use, so a search doesn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: A search for "fireball transmitter" points to an article here http://www.n5dux.com/ham/pubs/flyingpigs/BB0501.pdf which seems relevant

Answer (score 5):

This design could be using the key to control a tiny relay (possibly inside a Dual Inline Package) to connect and disconnect a tiny low power oscillator from the antenna feed.

Answer (score 0):

[DIP = **D**ual **I**nline **P**ackage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package).

Comment: Until today, I thought DIP meant Dual Inline Pins.